How can you go from a probability density to a transition probability density?
For the past few days I have been studying Advanced statistical mechanics. However I find that the question I have is somewhat more mathematical, it goes as follows. I am studying a Wiener process in general. Such a process is a non-stationaty time-independent Gaussian process. The probability density at a time t is given by
$$\rho_t(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4Dt}}.$$
I am now wondering how you get the transition probability density from this which is, in this case, given by
$$\rho_t(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt}}e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{4Dt}}.$$
A quick look makes me think you should just replace $x$ by $x-y$, however my question is more general in the sense that what if I have some probability distribution how do I compute the transition probability distribution from this?

In general, you can't - two processes can have the same distribution at any time, but have different transition distribution. Transition probability density is part of definition of Wiener process.

oh ok, so the transition probability density in my question is just defined and not derived?

There are multiple equivalent definitions (some of them are listed in wiki, probably there are more). In some of them transition probability is stated, in some something else is stated and transition probability is derived.
